# Can I deploy a WP7 application from Visual Studio to an AT&T phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

AT&T WP7 phones are locked to third-party applications.  Does this mean that during development I won't be able to deploy my applications from Visual Studio to the device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SDK includes a tool called "Windows Phone Developer Registration".  Once you've registered with the marketplace you can use this tool to unlock a device and deploy to it directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: Wow, sorry it took me so long to select this answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. To unlock phone, you need to pay Microsoft a fee of $99 annually to get membership of App Hub (http://create.msdn.com/en-US/). Then you can unlock the phone for development. When I checked you could unlock 3 phones at any given time.
2. For development without a phone, you can use the emulator which ships with Windows 7 phone SDK. This doesnt require a phone and i am not sure if all the features of phones are available are not.
3. Now that you are member,assuming you paid the fee, you can upload you application at App hub. Microsoft will then publish after testing, quality checks etc on the store. But paying the fee doesn't mean you have to publish your application. You may just keep the application to yourself.

Comment: You do not need to upload any files to load them on to a device for testing/development. Once the device is unlocked you can deploy to it directly from Visual Studio. You only need to upload he XAP file when you want to submit it to the marketplace.

Comment: well, you do *technically* upload them for MS to test... so that's not *entirely* wrong.

Comment: My idea of mentioning uploading to website was when you done making your application you can upload it to the website for further testing and selling.For unlocking you need to pay that fee and then unlock using the website's Dashboard section. And yes, when you install the windows 7 phone SDK, visual studio provides you with an emulator/phone option for running the app.

Comment: To make it clear: you need to pay for a Marketplace registration in order to test your application on the phone, regardless of the fact whether you want to publish the app to the Marketplace or not. There is *no* custom website given to you - you are able to upload the XAP file on AppHub *only* if you want to publish the app to the Marketplace. Debugging on the phone *does not* require you to submit the XAP to Microsoft.